# Unable to debug Configure method in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an Asp.Net core app and trying to seed the database. I have written the logic to initiate the seed in my Startup.cs Configure method. When I put a breakpoint and press F5, I am not able to debug. It dosent seem hitting the breakpoint. Can anybody point out what I am missing. Is there any issue with my seed logic as well. If you can see the there is a call to the context.EnsureSeedData(context). The application seems to disonnect and get the following error message

This site can’t be reached.localhost refused to connect.

I am using IISExpress

**Startup.cs File Configure method**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
        {


            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<CustomerOrderEntities>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
                context.EnsureSeedData(context);
            }


            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });

            // If you want to dispose of resources that have been resolved in the
            // application container, register for the "ApplicationStopped" event.
            appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
        }
```

**EnsureSeedData method**

```
public void EnsureSeedData(CustomerOrderEntities context)
        {



            if (!context.Customers.Any())
            {

                context.State.AddRange(
                   new State { Abbreviation = "AL", Name = "Alabama" },
                   new State { Abbreviation = "AK", Name = "Alaska" },
                   new State { Abbreviation = "AZ", Name = "Arizona" },
                   new State { Abbreviation = "AR", Name = "Arkansas" },
                   new State { Abbreviation = "OH", Name = "Ohio" });
                context.SaveChanges();

                context.Customers.AddRange(
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Jade", LastName = "Lawrence", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 1 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Robinson", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Dan", LastName = "Cruise", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Menon", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 1 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Tyson", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Ben", LastName = "Jones", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Foreman", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Henry", LastName = "Canvedalle", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Blake", LastName = "Walter", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 4 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "David", LastName = "Beckham", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 4 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Strand", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 4 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Jammie", LastName = "Oliver", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 },
                    new Customers { FirstName = "Ben", LastName = "Affleck", Gender =  Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 });

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

Comment: Add the seed initializer to the end of the Configure method in the Startup.cs file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql

Answer (score 0):

To seed data in your databank you better do the following:

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    ...

    app.UseMvc();

    //Init the database
    DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
}
```

**DbInitializer.cs (put this in the Data folder beside your context class)**

```
public static class DbInitializer
{

    public static void Initialize(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        EnsureSeedData(context);
    }

    private void EnsureSeedData(CustomerOrderEntities context)
    {

        if (!context.Customers.Any())
        {

            context.State.AddRange(
               new State { Abbreviation = "AL", Name = "Alabama" },
               new State { Abbreviation = "AK", Name = "Alaska" },
               new State { Abbreviation = "AZ", Name = "Arizona" },
               new State { Abbreviation = "AR", Name = "Arkansas" },
               new State { Abbreviation = "OH", Name = "Ohio" });
            context.SaveChanges();

            context.Customers.AddRange(
                new Customers { FirstName = "Jade", LastName = "Lawrence", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 1 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Robinson", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Dan", LastName = "Cruise", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Menon", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 1 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Tyson", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Ben", LastName = "Jones", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Foreman", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 2 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Henry", LastName = "Canvedalle", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Blake", LastName = "Walter", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 4 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "David", LastName = "Beckham", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 4 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Strand", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 4 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Jammie", LastName = "Oliver", Gender = Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 },
                new Customers { FirstName = "Ben", LastName = "Affleck", Gender =  Gender.Male, Email = "ranjit.menon9@gmail.com", Address = "ABC Farms", City = "London", StateId = 3 });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am however not able to debug the application itself. I am getting an error message Connection refused when I F5 my visual studio 2015 application

Comment: Also I dont see much difference between what you have suggested as I have EnsureSeedData in my Context class and calling it from my startup file

Comment: That is true, but it is cleaner :). Concerning visual studio: I don't have an answer there as I am using visual code